# Access Bound Data in ListBox.ItemTemplate using Custom Control (Silverlight 4)

Tags: silverlight-4.0, listbox, custom-controls

I Have a ListBox and I am defining its ItemsTemplate using a custom control. I want the control to be displayed in different ways depending on the state of cetain properties of the object. How can I access the item that the ListBox.ItemTemplate is bound to?

```
    <ListBox>
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <custom:MyControl />
       </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
```

With in the code of the custom control how would I do something like:

```
if((this.DataContext as SomeObject).CollectionProperty.Count() > 0)
  DoAction();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was accessing dataContext in the constructor and it was null. I accessed it in the this.Loaded event and it worked fine.